# Blazor c#, protection ServerSide application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, blazor

First, I am trying to understand how to protect blazor application from attacks.
I have a JavaScript function that calls c # code. I've noticed that when I publish a project, the static files are not obfuscated. This means that I can see the code of my js files on the client side and I can easily modify these files. I wonder how to protect this situation as an attacker can inject an infinite loop into my application, then the server side CPU will process this call.

For example:

I have line:

```js
callback.invokeMethodAsync('OnEvent', "sample data");
```

attacker can write this in devtool on client side:

```js
while(true) 
   callback.invokeMethodAsync('OnEvent', "sample data");
```

Then my application processes infinitely with the method:

```cs
OnEvent(string data)
```

The second problem is the transparency of static files in the **./_content** folder.
I can see all the libraries used in my project. I think this is a potentially dangerous problem because when the library manufacturer makes a vulnerability, my entire application is exposed to attack.
Has anyone had a similar problem? Maybe there is a way to fix these imperfections.

Comment: What do you suppose are the consequences of an attacker inflicting an infinite loop on his or her own browser?  That it will spam the server?  That can already happen today by anyone with access to a tool that can make API calls.  As for any of your other concerns, they are no different than any web site using standard HTML and Javascript.

Comment: In your invokeMethodAsync example, wouldn't making the method idempotent (i.e. it produces the same result no matter how many times it is called) mitigate any serious damage?  As @KirkWoll points out (despite not knowing what the word "spam" means), writing an infinite loop on such a method would simply waste time.

Comment: Microsoft does provide guidance for DOS attacks on Blazor apps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/threat-mitigation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#denial-of-service-dos-attacks-1).

Comment: @KirkWoll Yes, but I'm looking for a way to stop these attacks, sort of like Anti-DDoS in DDos attacks. For example, it break connection with specyfic client on too many calls

Comment: @RobertHarvey The only waste is resource consumption. Thank you for link.

Comment: May you know how can I hide names of library from content directory?